# Partion the boundary of a $n$-dimensional ball and write each partition as the graph of a $C^1$-function on a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, geometry, differential-geometry

Let $$S:=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\left\|x\right\|_2\le r\right\}$$ How can we partition the boundary $\partial S$ of $S$ and write each partition as the graph of a continuously differentiable function $h$ on a open set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?.

---

If $n=3$, we can choose $$\Omega=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x_1|<1\text{ and }|x_2|<\sqrt{r^2-x_1^2}\right\}$$ and $$h:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto\sqrt{r^2-\left\|x\right\|_2^2}$$ for the upper hemisphere. How can we extend this approach to the general case? The other partition (the lower hemisphere) can be written analogously.

Comment: for n=3. the graph of $h$ is a $\underline{half}$ sphere. Your $S$ is a ball. 
Note that usually a graph of a map from $ \Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$ has dimension $dim(\Omega)$.

Comment: ur sphere is of radius $r$. U should change the one in $\sqrt{1-()^2}$. And take $\Omega$ a corresponding disc!

Comment: The projection of the graph of a continuous function onto the domain of the function is a continuous surjection. As $\partial S$ is compact (and not empty) , this means it cannot be the graph of a function defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.  Your question was making more sense before you edited it to make it stop talking about the upper and lower hemispheres.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Are you looking to describe a sphere in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ as the union of $2n$ open hemispheres (not just two), each a graph? If so, could you please try to clarify the question? As is, it's not clear (to me) what you don't understand: The strategy you outline for $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ extends in a natural way....

Comment: @user86418: Maybe that is what the OP wants, but the question is phrased in terms of graphs of functions, which implies some fixed view of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$. Apologies for doubting your used of $2n$ in an earlier comment. In fact $n+1$ is enough, see http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h452866p2545912.

Comment: @user86418: As it is phrased in terms of graphs of functions, I think the question has to be answered in terms of a fixed representation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$. Apologies for  questioning your $2n$ in my earlier comment on your alternative interpretation of the question. In fact it turns out that $n+1$ hemispheres will always be sufficient to cover a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, see http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h452866p2545912.

Comment: @RobArthan: I agree with you entirely about the current wording and your interpretation. :) (The only reason I haven't upvoted your answer yet is to give the OP a chance to clarify their intent.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, even if you relax the question to allow the functions on the open sets to be discontinuous. For simplicity, take $r = 1$ and consider any point $e$ on the "equator" $\partial S \cap \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Any open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ containing $e$ contains a point $x$ with $\|x\|_2 > 1$. But if $h$ is any function $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then the point $(x, h(x))$ is in the graph of $h$ and has $\|(x, h(x))\|_2 > 1$. So $x \in \Omega$, but $(x, h(x)) \not\in \partial S$.